# Creating unique ArrayList for each Hash Map key value - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, maps

I am trying to read in information about the inputs to each gate in a circuit simulator I'm making. The file information for the input connections looks like this:

> // Connections from inputs to gates (inputLabel, gateLabel)
>   INPUT(A, AND1)
>   INPUT(B, AND1)
>   INPUT(B, AND2)
>   INPUT(C, AND2)

I am trying to create a Map with the key being the gateLabel, and storing the inputLabel information.

I.e. -

> Key --- Info
>         AND1 |   A,B
>         AND2  |  B,C

The code I have at the moment is this:

```
String inputCircuitLabel = params[0];
String inGateLabel = params[1];

    if(!iConnM.containsKey(inGateLabel)){

          inputCircuitLabels.add(inputCircuitLabel);
          iConnM.put(inGateLabel, inputCircuitLabels);              

    }

    else{

          inputCircuitLabels.add(inCircuitLabel);

    }
```

I was wondering if there is an intuitive way to make a separate class, and make a call to it something like:

```
GateInput gi = new GateInput(inGateLabel);
ArrayList<GateInput> al;
```

In order to get a unique arrayList for each gateLabel. Because at the moment AND2 ends up referencing A,B,B,C instead of just B,C.

Comment: Would using a `Map<String, Set<String>>` suffice?

Comment: Or `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a Map of String->List.  Using this approach, each gate label will get it's own unique List of circuit labels.

Example code:

```
Map<String, List<String>> iConnM = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

String inputCircuitLabel = params[0];
String inGateLabel = params[1];

if (!iConnM.containsKey(inGateLabel)) {
    iConnM.put(inGateLabel, Arrays.asList(inputCircuitLabel));
} else {
    iConnM.get(inGateLabel).add(inputCircuitLabel);
}
```

Comment: This worked. I just had to add 'new' in order to use a resizable List (and actually copy the contents because the initial List is not resizable). Here's what I eventually got `iConnM.put(inGateLabel, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inputCircuitLabel)));` Thank you.